# Couchbase Web UI not loading on Debian 7 on Google Compute Engine

Tags: debian, couchbase, google-compute-engine

I'm running Couchbase 2.1.1 on Debian 7 w/Backports and am having an issue loading the Web UI.  I continue to get "Could Not Connect" errors, despite being able to successfully access the UI (or at least the index.html) via a wget command.

So I know the ports are open and I know the UI is running, but simply can't connect to the interface from a browser.

Any ideas on how to further troubleshoot this?

Comment: Can you share your wget command and adress that you're trying to access. Also are you executing wget and browser at the same machine?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you're running the wget command on the VM and the web browser from another machine? If so, I'm guessing that you need to open the Compute Engine firewall to allow traffic on the ports used by the web UI. For example (for the default Couchbase web UI port):

```
gcutil --project=myproject addfirewall --allowed=tcp:8901 couchbase-webui
```

You can also add the firewall via the [Console](https://cloud.google.com/console). Click Compute Engine, then Networks, then click the default network. In the firewalls section, click "Add new", and fill in the details.

Comment: Nope, browser and wget are on the same external box and all required ports are open. I ended up just using the cli to do the configuration, though have no idea why I can't gain access to the UI.

Comment: Hmm... that is strange. Glad to hear you got it working. Maybe your browsers configured to go through a proxy which is blocking things somehow?